# sql server 2008 cant insertproduct key

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 in a Windows Server 2008, but when i have to enter the product key, all option are blocked, and I can´t put the key or select a evaluation version.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UqN1.png]

Comment: Did you get the installer from downloading the Express version?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Express installer. Download the full version ISO.